# Does the lambda operator have additional uses in a C# Universal Windows 10 app?

Tags: c#, lambda, win-universal-app, c#-6.0

I was looking through some C# UWP 10 source code and came across the following class member variable declaration:

```
public Frame RootFrame => Frame;
```

I would expect the lambda expression to be on the right side of an assignment operation. Is this a new syntactical feature of C#6 or UWP 10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C# 6 brings a new feature family called Expression Bodied Members, which includes *expression properties* and *expression functions*. It is merely syntactical sugar for single line properties and functions.

When you declare this:

```
public string Name => "BCA";
public int GetLuckyNumber() => 42;
```

The compiler does this for you:

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return "BCA";
    }
}

public int GetLuckyNumber()
{
    return 42;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a new language syntax introduced in C# 6 called **expression bodied functions and properties**. Check these articles:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/66489a/expression-bodied-members-in-C-Sharp-6-0/

http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/12/csharp-6-expression-bodied-method.html